# Can you contract "Where Will"?

Tags: grammar, word-usage

I took an English test the other day, however, our English teacher contested the "where'll" I have used in the following sentence:

Where'll they go? Not far away I hope.

After then doubting myself, a quick search has directed me to a dictionary page where where'll is listed as a normal contraction.

I plan on confronting this teacher about it as I have heard from other students that the teacher tends to do things "her own way".

Thanks in advance!

Comment: There is nothing technically ungrammatical about *where'll*. But, stylistically, it should not be used in formal writing.

Comment: You **took** an English test **the other day**. When referring to a time in the past, don't use the present perfect.

Comment: The contraction **where'll** is not universal.  It is not used in the dialect of American English that I speak, for example, which is spoken in Washington D.C., eastern Maryland, Delaware, eastern Pennsylvania, and southern New Jersey. I'd like to know where it's used, if at all.

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo I hear it all the time in the Midwestern US. Wouldn't write it formally, though. (It fits right in with *where're* and *where'd* for *where are* and *where did*, also common here in speech but not writing. Well, actually I probably have texted *where'd*, as in "hey, where'd you go?" sent to my spouse in a big store.)

Comment: @1006a: Does it rhyme with  **squirrel**?

Comment: @Tᴚoɯɐuo No, it rhymes with **peril**. So two distinct syllables, first vowel is the vowel in the word "air" (same as the regular pronunciation of *where*), but with a reduced vowel in the second syllable (and no /w/ in the middle).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The contraction is sometimes heard in speech but is rarely rendered as a contraction in writing.  Some dictionaries do list it and it is sometimes used. Searchin [ngrams](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22where%27ll%22&tbm=bks&tbs=cdr:1,cd_min:1974,cd_max:2000&lr=lang_en) shows it is rare in comparison to other contractions.

I would suggest you should not use "where'll" in writing, except when quoting direct speech.

So you can say

> "Where'll he go?" he asked, "Not far I 'ope".

(Notice in this sample I've also shown a "dropped h".)  When not directly quoting you should use "where will" and "hope".